# Online Powerpoint Slide Editor

Tags: powerpoint, google-slides

Is there anything like Google Slides, which can be integrated into the app we are building?

If not, then atleast a way to programmatically import the ppt file, and navigate to the editor for editing?

Any suggestions will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

There's an official powerpoint [online editor](https://office.live.com/start/PowerPoint.aspx?WT.mc_id=O16_BingHP) now. You could theoretically put an iframe linking to this page. It seems to require a 365 or Microsoft account, though.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement and have tested both the online offerings of Microsoft Office (SharePoint, One Drive) and Google docs. However, I finally decided on Only Office (https://www.onlyoffice.com/). The reasons for this were:

1. The Google and Microsoft offerings didn't (AFAIAK) have the fine tuned security I needed for document editing and access via their various API (i.e. I needed to be able to prevent downloads of documents but allow editing)
2. Google and Microsoft require sign-in from their respective platforms to use these. This was a UX problem for my project.

Depending on the specific requirement Only Office has the Document Server on a GNU APGL v3 licence. You may need to buy a licence but worth a check.

Their repo is here:

https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/